# Get-ChildItem returning string when only 1 item exists

Tags: powershell

I'm using `$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Name` to get a list of folder names in the immediate folder.

However, when there is only 1 folder, it returns a string instead of an array.

How can I force it to return an array every time?

Comment: `$dirs=@(Get-ChildItem . -Name -Directory)` or `[array]$dirs=Get-ChildItem . -Name -Directory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#array-subexpression-operator--) - `@(...)`:

```
$dirs = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Name)

# This will now always hold true
$dirs -is [array]
```

Comment: Or this as well `[array]$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Name`